# aws cli returns error object has no attribute _get_hostport

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I'm getting an error today while running the following command:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances
```

The error I am getting is:

```
'AWSHTTPSConnection' object has no attribute '_get_hostport'
```

I can't seem to find anything related to this error. I colleague of mine is running it just fine. Mine was working a month ago but started giving me this error today.

Comment: Your region might be mis-configured. Use `aws configure` to define your region. Also might be worth updating your awscli to the latest version (on Linux: `sudo pip install awscli --upgrade`).

Comment: My colleague is using the same version as me and it worked. I ended up just uninstalling and installing it again and now things seem to be fine.